# nodejs multer file size by file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multer

I have a multer code blog, to set a size limit according to the type of file I want to make (limits-fileSize) i have no idea how to do it.

Example:

```
const filetypesImg = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/; - 4mb
const filetypesVideo = /mp4|avi/; 10mb
const filetypesSound = /mp3|mp4|flac|wav|m4a/; 1mb
```

actually I want to add limitation to the types like above

Comment: are you using multiple file uploads, or single files? Btw what you want is not possible using multer for the same route.

Comment: I want to use for single file upload, Although I did research, I could not reach any results. I think I need to make a custom filter, I tried but I failed